# Generalize Google Sheets script that merges duplicate rows in array to work on more then singe column

Tags: google-apps-script, merge

I need to merge duplicate rows in an array and concatenate cells in multiple columns.

Script to do this on a single column gotten here:
[google script sheet, merging rows duplicate in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66608202/google-script-sheet-merging-rows-duplicate-in-array)

| Id | From | To | Transaction | Flow | Running Balance | Description | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| conn-1 | Alan | Alícia | Giving1 | 1 | 60 | Stuff1 | 20/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-2 | Alan | Ashish | Giving2 | 2 | 62 | Stuff2 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-3 | Alan | Ashish | Giving3 | 3 | 59 | Stuff3 | 26/11/2022 | Person |
| conn-4 | Alan | Deborah | Giving4 | 15 | 48 | Stuff4 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-5 | Christine | Deborah | Giving5 | 1 | 47 | Stuff5 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-6 | Christine | Deborah | Giving6 | 4 | 61 | Stuff6 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-7 | Christine | Deborah | Giving7 | 4 | 61 | Stuff7 | 26/10/2023 | Person |
| conn-7 | Christine | Gitanjali | Giving8 | 1 | 54 | Stuff8 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-8 | Christine | Jacklina | Giving9 | 7 | 43 | Stuff9 | 26/10/2022 | Person |

If run merrgRows on the `Transaction` column, I get

| Id | From | To | Transaction | Flow | Running Balance | Description | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| conn-1 | Alan | Alícia | Giving1 | 1 | 60 | Stuff1 | 20/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-2 | Alan | Ashish | Giving2|Giving3 | 2 | 62 | Stuff2 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-4 | Alan | Deborah | Giving4 | 15 | 48 | Stuff4 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-5 | Christine | Deborah | Giving5|Giving6|Giving7 | 1 | 47 | Stuff5 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-7 | Christine | Gitanjali | Giving8 | 1 | 54 | Stuff8 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-8 | Christine | Jacklina | Giving9 | 7 | 43 | Stuff9 | 26/10/2022 | Person |

Which is what I want.

But I need to concatenate multiple columns, not just on `Transaction.`

Original script

```
function mergeRow (rows) {
    let newRows = []
    let matched = []
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        
        if (!matched.includes(i)) {
            let a = rows[i]
            let nextIndex = i+1
            let matches = []
            
            for (var x = nextIndex; x < rows.length; x++) {
                if (a[1] === rows[x][1] && a[2] === rows[x][2]) {
                    matches.push(x);
                }
            }
            
            let newRow = a,
                n = 3,
                lastItem = a[n];
            
            matches.forEach(index => {
                lastItem += ':' + rows[index][n]
                matched.push(index)
            })
            
            newRow[n] = lastItem
            newRows.push(newRow)
        }
    }
    return newRows 
}
```

My attempt to generalize mergeRow

```
function mergeRow2 (rows) {
    let newRows = []
    let matched = []
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        
        if (!matched.includes(i)) {
            let a = rows[i]      //iterating trough each row
            let nextIndex = i+1
            let matches = [] 
            for (var x = nextIndex; x < rows.length; x++) {
                if (a[1] === rows[x][1] && a[2] === rows[x][2]) {
                    matches.push(x);
                }
            }

          let cols = [3,6]; 

          cols.forEach(function(n){  
            var newRow = a
            var lastItem = a[n]  // The Input values for the first part of the concatenation
            
              matches.forEach(index => {
                  lastItem += '|' + rows[index][n] //The column values to be concatenated to lastItem
                  matched.push(index)
              })

            newRow[n] = lastItem //The OUTPUT Column
            newRows.push(newRow)
          })         
      }
    }
    return newRows
}
```

I get

| Id | From | To | Transaction | Flow | Running Balance | Description | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | From | To | Transaction | Flow | Running Balance | Description | Date | Type |
| conn-1 | Alan | Alícia | Giving1 | 1 | 60 | Stuff1 | 20/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-1 | Alan | Alícia | Giving1 | 1 | 60 | Stuff1 | 20/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-2 | Alan | Ashish | Giving2|Giving3 | 2 | 62 | Stuff2|Stuff3 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-2 | Alan | Ashish | Giving2|Giving3 | 2 | 62 | Stuff2|Stuff3 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-4 | Alan | Deborah | Giving4 | 15 | 48 | Stuff4 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-4 | Alan | Deborah | Giving4 | 15 | 48 | Stuff4 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-5 | Christine | Deborah | Giving5|Giving6|Giving7 | 1 | 47 | Stuff5|Stuff6|Stuff7 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-5 | Christine | Deborah | Giving5|Giving6|Giving7 | 1 | 47 | Stuff5|Stuff6|Stuff7 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-7 | Christine | Gitanjali | Giving8 | 1 | 54 | Stuff8 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-7 | Christine | Gitanjali | Giving8 | 1 | 54 | Stuff8 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-8 | Christine | Jacklina | Giving9 | 7 | 43 | Stuff9 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-8 | Christine | Jacklina | Giving9 | 7 | 43 | Stuff9 | 26/10/2022 | Person |

What I need

| Id | From | To | Transaction | Flow | Running Balance | Description | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| conn-1 | Alan | Alícia | Giving1 | 1 | 60 | Stuff1 | 20/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-2 | Alan | Ashish | Giving2|Giving3 | 2 | 62 | Stuff2|Stuff3 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-4 | Alan | Deborah | Giving4 | 15 | 48 | Stuff4 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-5 | Christine | Deborah | Giving5|Giving6|Giving7 | 1 | 47 | Stuff5|Stuff6|Stuff7 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-7 | Christine | Gitanjali | Giving8 | 1 | 54 | Stuff8 | 26/10/2022 | Person |
| conn-8 | Christine | Jacklina | Giving9 | 7 | 43 | Stuff9 | 26/10/2022 | Person |

How to concatenate multiple columns?

Google sheet with data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GOevQJXEQAvljesu46SYWD4Yvfi-FCLl39EtCdBBa0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I generalized a bit more)

```
//mC1 1st column index to test for dups
//mC2 2nd column index to test for dups
//Array of column indices to concatenate when merging rows duplicates in array
function mergeRow2(rows,mC1,mC2, cols) {
    let newRows = [],
        matched = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        
        if (!matched.includes(i)) {
            let a         = rows[i],
                nextIndex = i+1,
                matches   = [];
            
            for (var x = nextIndex; x < rows.length; x++) {
                if (a[mC1] === rows[x][mC1] && a[mC2] === rows[x][mC2]) {
                    matches.push(x);
                }
            }
            
            let newRow   = a,
                lastItem = [];

            for(var n=0; n<= cols.length-1; n++) {
              matches.forEach(index => {
                lastItem = a[cols[n]]
                lastItem += '|' + rows[index][cols[n]]
                matched.push(index)

                newRow[cols[n]] = lastItem
              })
            }
          
             newRows.push(newRow)  
        };
    }

    return newRows
}
```